# Re-Organize Access Table by converting Rows to Columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, ms-access, transform

I'm pretty new to access and SQL and need some help re-organizing a table.  I have the following table (sorry for the table below - having trouble posting):

```
ID   GroupID  Distance  Code  Start_Finish
1   44       7         A     S1
2   44       14        A     F1
3   45       12        B     S1
4   45       16        B     F1
5   45       31        C     S2
6   45       36        C     F2
7   45       81        B     S3
8   45       88        B     F3
```

And need for the table to be transformed into:

```
GroupID  Code  Start_Distance  Finish_Distance
44       A     7               14
45       B     12              16
45       C     31              36
45       B     81              88
```

Comment: What is the access part and what is the sql server part?

Comment: Any hints about the relationship between the datasets in T1 and T2? Or are we meant to work it out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try something like this

```
Select GroupID, Code, min(distance) as Start_distance, max(distance) as Finish_distance
from Table
group by GroupID, Code
```

If the min and max functions don't give you what you need, try it with First() and Last() instead.

Oops - just noticed you have 2 different entries in the output for GroupID 45 Code B - is that a requirement?  With that data structure and requirement, the problem gets much more difficult.

Now I see the final column in the 1st table - I think that can be used to get the output you want:

```
Select GroupID, Code, mid(start_finish,2) as T, min(distance) as Start_distance, max(distance) as Finish_distance
from Table
group by GroupID, Code, T
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use conditional aggregation for this.

```
select GroupID
    , CODE
    , max(case when Left(Start_Finish, 1) = 'S' then Distance end) as Start_Distance
    , max(case when Left(Start_Finish, 1) = 'F' then Distance end) as Finish_Distance
from SomeTable
group by GroupID
    , CODE
```